# How to ask user for relogin when his browser history get cleared?

Tags: php, session, cookies, authentication

I have used a session variable to store the logged in username. If the user is logged in properly, the particular protected page get displayed, and if not he is redirected to the log in page. The code works fine. But the problem is that, if the user cleared the browser history after logged in, he still can view the particular protected page. What I want is to redirect him to the log in page when he cleared the browser history. Please suggest me how to do this.

Comment: if u clear cookies then u have to required login again in your site..and if u clear only history of your browser then dont reqired login again

Answer (score 1):

The session variables in PHP work on cookies, by default. There is no way to detect whether the user has cleared his history, but the user will be automatically logged out when they clear **cookies**.